# scrollHeight и clientHeight равны 0 JS

Tags: javascript

```
function addButton(i) {
    let scrollHeight = budgetBox[i].scrollHeight,
        height = budgetBox[i].clientHeight;

    if ( height < scrollHeight - 6) {
        more[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        more[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Такой странный баг у меня... Есть функция, которая срабатывает после добавления категории в блок с конкретной высотой, если высота блока совпадает с высотой его прокрутки, тогда кнопка "ещё" удаляется, если же высота прокрутки больше высоты блока, тогда кнопка появляется. Первые 2 проверки (выполнения функции) при загрузке сайта работают хорошо, но после срабатывания функции добавления новой категории в блок и после callbacka'а интересующей меня функции, оба параметра высоты почему-то становятся равны нулю. Я чего то не понимаю, или, при обновлении DOM-контента при помощи JS, высота блока теряется?

Comment: Во-первых, при чем тут метка `ecmascript-6`? Во -вторых, скорее всего у тебя  функция срабатывает до того, как полностью загружается контент, добавь `setInterval`  и проверь...

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Air за совет про setInterval, только у меня организация кода такова, что это не сработало.

В общем, если у вас возникла такая же проблема, то поставьте функцию с проверкой DOM-контента после всех других функций, связанных с изменениями этого самого контента.

Типо чтобы было не так

```
function() {

     check(...); //интересующая нас функция

     add(...);

     move(...);
}
```

А так:

```
function() {

        add(...);

        move(...);

        check(...); //интересующая нас функция
}
```